# `Theme` editor and programmatic methods to set Styles use completely different units

Tags: codenameone

This is my first attempt to develop a mobile application on Codename One. I am working on the presentation layer currently.

I notice there is an inconsistency between the `Theme` editor and the programmatic `set` and `get` methods of the available options.

E.g. in the editor, I set the colors in Hex since I use Material Design Color Tool Standards. When I try to reset a `Component`'s color programmatically, I have the option to set it using only `int RRGGBB` argument.
Another example, I set the margin and padding units to millimeters in the `Theme` editor, but programmatically, there is no constant argument for millimeters option.

Please, if my assertions are wrong, leave a comment below to point my attention to it.

Comment: I would recommend you move to CSS for the design. We're focusing on that moving forward and de-emphasizing the designer.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your two observations:

**colors in Hex and colors as Integer**

Suppose you are interested in the "Light Blue 50" Material color, which hex value is: `#E1F5FE`. To express it as Integer, you should prefix the hex value with `0x`, in this way: `0xE1F5FE`. This is your Integer. See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hexadecimal-integer-literal-in-java

**margin and padding units to millimeters**

You must use the `Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS` to indicate millimeters, in this context they have the same meaning. I understand that you may be confused about that. In the javadoc (https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/plaf/Style.html#UNIT_TYPE_DIPS), you can read:

> Indicates the unit type for padding/margin in device independent
> pixels. **Device independent pixels try to aim at roughly 1 millimeter
> of the screen per DIP** but make no guarantee for accuracy.

For example, to set a margin and a padding of half millimeter:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
Button myBtn = new Button("My fun button 1", "Button-Red");
myBtn.getAllStyles().setMarginUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);
myBtn.getAllStyles().setMargin(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
myBtn.getAllStyles().setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);
myBtn.getAllStyles().setPadding(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
hi.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(myBtn));
hi.show();
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I sort of found out about the second point that DIPS are equivalent to millimeters.